# setOnCompletionListener issue

Tags: java, android-studio, android-mediaplayer, event-listener

Hey guys I'm totally new to java, trying to finish my first project for college. I want to finish the code with setting `OnCompletionListener` to set the sound to `null`. So, it looks like this:

```
package com.example.alaiborys.newfuckingshit;

public class campfire extends AppCompatActivity {
MediaPlayer campfiresound;
int paused;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_campfire);
}

public void play(View view) {
    if (campfiresound == null) {
        campfiresound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.campfire);
        campfiresound.start();
    }
    else if(!campfiresound.isPlaying())
    {
        campfiresound.seekTo(paused);
        campfiresound.start();
    }
}

public void stop(View view) {
    campfiresound.release();
    campfiresound = null;
}

public void pause(View view) {
    campfiresound.pause();
    paused = campfiresound.getCurrentPosition();
}
}
```

So, I want to add `OnCompletionListener():` but have no idea where to put it and how to code it, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Well that is pretty easy...you have a media player object **campfiresound**
so you need to regisdter the interface [OnCompletionListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener.html)

```
campfiresound.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
       //toast...am done!!
    }
});
```

Comment: emm ok, that's what I came up with, it's not recognizing it or what?https://s22.postimg.org/8lztdleld/problem.jpg

Comment: @BorysKuczkowski.. ok i get it.. just move the code of my answer and paste it after the initialization of the campfiresound object...